# Is it possible to create a C# Webservice that can receive mails?

Tags: c#, web-services, email, outlook

just a quick question:

Is it possible to write a C# Webservice that can receive emails?

Example:
I like to forward a mail from my Outlook inbox to this Webservice and based on some conditions (e.g. subject line has to contains some numbers / words) then this Webservice should do some stuff.

Is this possible? I already tried to find some Information about this but was not successfull.
Any ideas for what I have to search here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an Outlook plugin that calls a web service and passes the contents of the email. The web service could be written in C# using ServiceStack, Web API, or similar frameworks.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That could be maybe a plan B. But I prefer to do this without a Outlook plug-in because it is not possible for me to install this on all clients. How does the eBay System work? You can answer the mail that you receive and have it lator in your Messaging inbox from eBay... I`d like to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

i would use the exchange webservices for this task. These webservices allow you to read/ send emails from your exchange server so you would not even need to forward the emails.
You can setup criteria to retrieve emails, order the by receivedate, even filter based on the subject etc 
here is some sample code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877037(v=exchg.140).aspx

http://gregorsuttie.com/2011/10/07/using-the-exchange-web-service-api-from-c/

all you need to do is reference the exchange webservice from your own webservice.